# How to include a file depending on a request attribute using the include directive

Tags: jsp, jstl, directive

I would like to include a file depending on a request attribute value.

```
${theme} -> themeA
```

To sum up. I would like something like this:

```
<%@ include file="../themes/${theme}/jsp/content/welcome.jsp"%>
```

Any easy workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with <%@ include%> as that is a static/compile time include.
You could instead use <jsp:include> tag, which is evaluated at runtime, and includes the *result* of executing that page, rather than including the page itself at compile time.

To compare all the differences between the include directive and <jsp:include> check out [JSP2.0 Reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref20.html)

```
<jsp:include page="../themes/${theme}/jsp/content/welcome.jsp">
```

The <c:import> tag would also work if you are using JSTL.

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:import url="../themes/${theme}/jsp/content/welcome.jsp"/>
```

Comment: This also works. Is there any difference between `<c:import url="..."/>` and `<jsp:include page="...">` ?

Comment: Yes, actually, c:import requires the JSTL library, so I guess evnafets's solution is better (since he mentions both).

Comment: Ok, I could have guessed that. We're forced by our college to only use jstl (no idea why though) So your example was still useful (+1)